# Proof of independence (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that {1,sin(x),sin(2x),sin(3x),…,sin(nx)} is an independent set. I received 1 answer 3 days ago but didn't find the answer very clear.

Please advice, thanks!

Comment: Your previous post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505357/proof-that-this-is-independent